# Cordova 5.4.0: Plugin folder & Cordova_Plugin file missing in APK Cause App Carsh

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Using Cordova 5.4.0

We tried to create APK file-cordova build android --debub/--release. App start crash. we extract APK file and check the folder which we noticed that the "Plugin" folder and 'cordova_plugin.js' file not generated inside "assets/www".

But we tried the same using other version like 5.1.1 and 5.3.3, the plugin and cordova_plugin file available inside the APK and it is working as expected.

Kindly let me know anyone face the same problem or similar and share if any clue or some valuable information on this.

Thanks, Hari

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was a regression with cordova 5.4.0 - see [this jira issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9976), and then the [cordova-lib changelog for 5.4.1](https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/blob/master/cordova-lib/RELEASENOTES.md).

I went ahead and upgraded to 5.4.1 and was successful in getting my plugins again.  Good luck!